# How to create a function that returns the sum of each character code(ASCII value) of the given string?

Tags: python

The question is as followed:
Define a class Append.
Use the parameterized constructor used to initialize the input string a.
Define a method that returns the sum of each character code(ASCII value) of the given string a.

Sample test case:

input(string):

```
CodeTantra
```

output:

```
997
```

Comment: This looks like a homework question. You need to learn how to find the numerical value of a character, as well as how to design a class to perform the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```py
s = sum(ord(x) for x in "CodeTantra")
```

This sums up the ASCII value of every character in the string `CodeTantra`, which yields `997`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
print(sum(map(ord, "CodeTantra"))) # 997
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class Append:
    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self.a = a

    def sum_char_codes(self):
        sum = 0
        for char in self.a:
            sum += ord(char)
        return sum

# Test the Append class
test = Append("CodeTantra")
print(test.sum_char_codes())
```